# Completness of the space $C_b^k(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I came across the following problem:

For an open set $U$ in  $\mathbb{R^n}$  we define the set of all k-times continuously differentiable functions $f\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which $D^\alpha f$ is uniformly bounded in $U$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N_0^n}$ with $|\alpha| \leqslant k$.
Define for $f\in C_b^k(U)$ :

$$\|f\|_k := \sum\limits_{|\alpha| \leqslant k} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \sup \{|D^{\alpha }f(x)| : x \in U\}.$$

I proved that this is a norm on $C_b^k$ and now I want to prove that the space ($C_b^k(U), \|.\|_k$) is complete which means each Cauchy sequence converges in this space but since this is a more abstract space than I am used to i find it hard to see how to continue.

I would appreciate some guidelines. Thank you

Comment: If $(f_n)$ is a $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_k$-Cauchy sequence, what can you say about the sequences $(D^\alpha f_n)$?

Comment: I would say that $D^\alpha f_n$ converges uniformly but it is still unclear how to prove this.

Comment: First of all, they are a $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_\infty$-Cauchy sequence, where $\lVert g\rVert_\infty = \sup \{ \lvert g(x)\rvert : x \in U\}$ is the sup-norm. Then you need to see that $C_b(U) = \{ g \in C(U) : \lVert g\rVert_\infty < \infty\}$ is complete in the sup-norm.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of proof.** Suppose you have a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}\subset C_b^k(U)$, with respect to $\|\cdot\|_k$.
Then, for every $\lvert\alpha\rvert\le k$, the sequence $\{D^\alpha f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy in $U$ and hence uniformly convergent to a continuous and bounded function, say $f^\alpha\in C_b(U)$ - All the $f^\alpha$'s are for the moment only continuous and bounded in $U$.

Next, we need to show that $f^0\in C_b^k(U)$ and $D^\alpha f=f^\alpha$.

This is done inductively on $\alpha$, starting in the following way:

$$
f_n\to f\quad\text{and}\quad \partial_{x_1} f_n\to f^(1,0,\ldots,0),
$$
implies that $f$ is differentiable, with respect to $x_1$ and $\partial_{x_1}=f^(1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: I don't see why the sequence $D^\alpha f_n$ will converge uniformly. Could you perhaps expand a bit? Thank you

Comment: @WhatsMyName: It is straight from the definition of the norm. If $\|f_m-f_n\|_k\to 0$, then equivalently $\{D^\alpha f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy, for all $|\alpha|\le k$.